# How to use ng-transclude to extend md-autocomplete? [Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template!]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to extend [md-autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/autocomplete) by wrapping it in my own directive like this:

```
//..other directive code    
template: '<div><md-autocomplete ng-transclude=""></md-autocomplete></div>';
transclude: true;
```

So hopefully, I can use this HTML:

```
<my-custom-autocomplete>
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
</my-custom-autocomplete>
```

So what I'm basically after is that when `<my-custom-autocomplete>` gets rendered the final code becomes something like this:

```
<my-custom-autocomplete><div><md-autocomplete><span>{{item.name}}</span></md-autocomplete></div></my-custom-autocomplete>
```

i.e. the html code inside `<my-custom-autocomplete>` will get transcluded in between the `<md-autocomplete>` directive.

Unfortunately this does not work and I keep getting this error:

```
angular.js:13550 Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <md-autocomplete ng-transclude="" tabindex="-1" class="ng-isolate-scope">
```

My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I include the HTML from my custom directive and place it between `<md-autocomplete>` before rendering?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem, and after a lot of tinkering, I have found a working solution. The md-autocomplete uses template manipulation instead of ng-transclusion to set the inner content. No matter where you put your transclusion tags, autocomplete will strip them off as it completely rewrites your html into the auto-complete html.

The solution turned out to be not relying on transclusion, but instead using the same type of template manipulation that Angular itself uses.

Here is a fiddle of a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Pluisjen/h3n1ch0f/

And here is the crux to having the option to overriding the md-item-template:

```
template: function(elem, attr) { 
    getItemTemplateHtml = function() { return elem.find('md-item-template').html() || 'Default by directive' }
    return '<md-autocomplete layout-margin' +
                       'md-selected-item="first"' +
                       'md-items="i in firstOptions"' +
                       'md-min-length="0"' +                     
                       'md-item-text="i"' +
                       'ng-transclude' +
                       'placeholder="First">' +      
      '<md-item-template>' + getItemTemplateHtml() + '</md-item-template>' +
      '</md-autocomplete>'; },
```